# JavaScript Button to update Section

Tags: javascript, html

I need to build JavaScript code to update Html Section element content but not to delete the existing content , just add on it, any advice?

*i searched and found an attribute "contenteditable" that can be set to "true" ,so that you can edit in the section ,i used below code*

```
let section = document.querySelector('section'); 
for (let s in section){ s.set attribute =("contenteditable","true")}
```

–

Comment: share your code with us

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), preferably as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be able to add some new content using `appendChild`, like:

```
const section = document.querySelector('section');
section.appendChild(document.createElement("DIV"));
```

Comment: i searched and found an attribute contenteditable that can be set to "true" ,so that you can edit in the section ,i used   l                                                                                                   
let  section = document.querySelector('section');                                                                       for (let s in section){ s.set attribute =("contenteditable","true")}